# Is there an efficient way of returning a sub-section of a text string

Tags: r

I am often needing to return a part of a text string(say the middle bit of text separated by "." with text on either end). I have ended up using a funky bit of code that essentially: 1. splits the string with `strsplit`, 2. `unlist` the string components, 3. make a `matrix` with the number of rows equaling the number of string sub-elements, and 4. subtract the row that I need. There's got to be a better way, right? Although it might be more straightforward, I am often unable to use `substr` because the length of the string components in not constant throughout the vector.

#### Example:

```
#make data
set.seed(1)
n <- 50
let1 <- LETTERS[runif(n, min=1, max=26)]
num <- round(runif(100, min=1, max=100))
let2 <- c(LETTERS[runif(n, min=1, max=26)], LETTERS[runif(n, min=1, max=26)])
tmpstr <- paste(let1, num, let2, sep=".")
tmpstr

#resulting string
> tmpstr
 [1] "G.48.P" "J.86.N" "O.44.I" "W.25.L" "F.8.M"  "W.11.E" "X.32.N"
 [8] "Q.52.B" "P.67.G" "B.41.F" "F.91.H" "E.30.W" "R.46.L" "J.34.T"
 [15] "T.65.W" "M.27.K" "R.48.B" "Y.77.I" "J.9.S"  "T.88.I" "X.35.P"
 [22] "F.84.V" "Q.35.V" "D.34.J" "G.48.J" "J.89.W" "A.87.Q" "J.40.S"
 [29] "V.78.P" "I.96.W" "M.44.H" "O.72.E" "M.41.W" "E.33.M" "U.76.V"
 [36] "Q.21.E" "T.71.S" "C.13.S" "S.25.X" "K.15.N" "U.25.R" "Q.7.J" 
 [43] "T.65.C" "N.88.X" "N.78.H" "T.80.O" "A.46.C" "L.42.V" "S.81.H"
 [50] "R.61.T" "G.66.G" "J.36.F" "O.28.M" "W.99.G" "F.64.E" "W.22.M"
 [57] "X.14.O" "Q.48.D" "P.92.G" "B.60.R" "F.98.Y" "E.73.C" "R.36.T"
 [64] "J.44.X" "T.16.U" "M.2.H"  "R.72.Q" "Y.11.X" "J.45.X" "T.64.I"
 [71] "X.99.G" "F.50.E" "Q.49.I" "D.18.M" "G.76.X" "J.46.M" "A.52.G"
 [78] "J.22.B" "V.24.K" "I.60.V" "M.58.I" "O.9.D"  "M.5.J"  "E.65.P"
 [85] "U.93.J" "Q.60.R" "T.57.R" "C.53.N" "S.99.K" "K.51.L" "U.69.H"
 [92] "Q.61.O" "T.25.W" "N.27.D" "N.73.K" "T.46.F" "A.18.K" "L.75.D"
 [99] "S.11.L" "R.87.X"

#possible substring extraction (e.g. the numbers in between the letters)
matrix(unlist(strsplit(tmpstr, ".", fixed = TRUE)), nrow=3)[2,] #version 1
unlist(lapply(as.list(tmpstr), FUN=function(x) strsplit(x, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2])) #version 2 - not much shorter

#desired result
  [1] "48" "86" "44" "25" "8"  "11" "32" "52" "67" "41" "91" "30" "46"
 [14] "34" "65" "27" "48" "77" "9"  "88" "35" "84" "35" "34" "48" "89"
 [27] "87" "40" "78" "96" "44" "72" "41" "33" "76" "21" "71" "13" "25"
 [40] "15" "25" "7"  "65" "88" "78" "80" "46" "42" "81" "61" "66" "36"
 [53] "28" "99" "64" "22" "14" "48" "92" "60" "98" "73" "36" "44" "16"
 [66] "2"  "72" "11" "45" "64" "99" "50" "49" "18" "76" "46" "52" "22"
 [79] "24" "60" "58" "9"  "5"  "65" "93" "60" "57" "53" "99" "51" "69"
 [92] "61" "25" "27" "73" "46" "18" "75" "11" "87"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to return anything between 2 points:

```
  gsub('.*[.](.*)[.].*','\\1',tmpstr)
```

Comment: Great stuff. Now I've got to finally dedicate myself to learning perl-type scripting ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to do anything as complicated - you can use the awesome package stringr's function str_extract

```
str_extract(tmpstr,"[0-9]")
```

This uses regex to extract only the numbers.  Obviously, your real data might make this more complicated, but this should hopefully give you a good starting point.

**Edit**
A specific extraction between two full-stops, with the full-stops removed (with my poor regex skills I have to do it this long way)

`str_replace_all(str_extract(tmpstr,"[.][[:alnum:]]*[.]"),"\\.","")`

Comment: That's good to know, but I was actually hoping for a more general solution - where the target sub-string might not be numeric.

Comment: @Marcinthebox, updated to provide a more robust version that'd extract everything between the full-stops. agstudy's solution is much neater and I'd suggest it's better than an unlisting type of activity because you're using a function more directly related to the problem at hand, lending clarity to your code.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. Very unselfish of you - I agree that agstudy's approach is the clearest, but learned something here as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more possible solutions:

```
library(qdap)
unname(unlist(genXtract(tmpstr, ".", ".")))

do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmpstr, "\\."))[, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler for the suggestions. Didn't know I could collapse a list with `rbind`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few alternatives.  I would expect that the `gsub` solutions would be the fastest:

**1.** Delete all non-digits leaving only the digits remaining:

```
gsub("\\D", "", tmpstr)
```

**2.**  Rather than delete non digits we could pull out digits with strapplyc:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(tmpstr, "\\d+", simplify = TRUE)
```

**3.** If the middle field is not necessarily only digits then we could do this which deletes everything up to and including the first dot as well as the last dot and everything after it:

```
gsub("^.*?[.]|[.].*?$", "", tmpstr)
```

**4.** We could also use `read.table` in which case we do not need any regular expressions at all:

```
read.table(text = tmpstr, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE)[[2]]
```

**5.** Regarding an approach that works with `strsplit` try this:

```
simplify2array(strsplit(tmpstr, ".", fixed = TRUE))[2,]
```