# Return numbers between brackets

Tags: r

I'm a recreational programmer with no regex training so I'm struggling with this problem. I found an example here:

[Is there an efficient way of returning a sub-section of a text string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527469/is-there-an-efficient-way-of-returning-a-sub-section-of-a-text-string/17531817#17531817)

where gsub was used to extract numbers between two periods. I need to do the same thing however I'm looking for the numbers between square brackets, as in the tmpstr1. Could someone help me understand the regex in the gsub example so that I can modify it and get this to work? Basically, how does one read the regex part in English so it makes sense? I just don't get it.

Thanks

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 50
let1 <- LETTERS[runif(n, min=1, max=26)]
num <- round(runif(100, min=1, max=100))
let2 <- c(LETTERS[runif(n, min=1, max=26)], LETTERS[runif(n, min=1, max=26)])
tmpstr <- paste(let1, num, let2, sep=".")
tmpstr

gsub('.*[.](.*)[.].*','\\1',tmpstr)

tmpstr1 <- paste0(let1, "[", num, "]", let2)
tmpstr1
```

Comment: This also replaces the dots with [ ] and only involves fixed strings:   `sub(".", "]", sub(".", "[", tmpstr, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LGTrader's answer is better for those wanting to learn regex (my vote's there) but this is for those who don't want to learn regex:

```
library(qdap)
x <- bracketXtract(tmpstr1, "square")
unname(unlist(x))

## > unname(unlist(bracketXtract(tmpstr1, "square")))
##   [1] "48" "86" "44" "25" "8"  "11" "32" "52" "67" "41" "91" "30" "46" "34" "65"
##  [16] "27" "48" "77" "9"  "88" "35" "84" "35" "34" "48" "89" "87" "40" "78" "96"
##  [31] "44" "72" "41" "33" "76" "21" "71" "13" "25" "15" "25" "7"  "65" "88" "78"
##  [46] "80" "46" "42" "81" "61" "66" "36" "28" "99" "64" "22" "14" "48" "92" "60"
##  [61] "98" "73" "36" "44" "16" "2"  "72" "11" "45" "64" "99" "50" "49" "18" "76"
##  [76] "46" "52" "22" "24" "60" "58" "9"  "5"  "65" "93" "60" "57" "53" "99" "51"
##  [91] "69" "61" "25" "27" "73" "46" "18" "75" "11" "87"
```

Comment: You could clean this up a little bit - it's not apparent why you define `x` and then completely disregard it the next line.

Answer (score 2):

After posting the question I found an example that seems to work:

```
gsub('.+\\[([0-9]+)\\].+?$', '\\1', tmpstr1)
```